# Why does this Syntax Error appear and how do I troubleshoot it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to run the sample React code in, however, when I do it, it gives me the following SynthaxError:

```
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47´
```

Comment: can you share where are you placing the code?

Comment: okay thanks I solved it